# Can I create a block that shows custom node types but in a specific order?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

For example, I have custom block made with Views that shows some block icons that are links to modules.

I would like to rearrange them.

For example, I would like to say "Put node 3 first, then node 5, then node 1".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module, it may solve your problem.

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as:
>
> - A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
> - A user’s favorite music albums
> - A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
>
> Nodequeue provides a simple drag-and-drop interface to manually order any queue. Additionally, it allows nodes to be added and removed from queues without needing edit permissions to the node. Nodes can be added to queues either from a queue management tab or by links on the node teaser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using views then [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) is the module you are looking for , this is the description from its project page :

> DraggableViews makes rows of a view "draggable" which means that they can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.
>
> Have you ever rearranged Blocks?, sorted Taxonomy terms? or reordered Menu items at the Drupal administration pages? All these pages use the tabledrag.js javascript that enables Drag'n Drop on HTML-tables.
>
> With DraggableViews you can apply this tabledrag.js to any Views-generated table.

Answer (score 0):

[Node Queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module let you specified a cusomize order of sorting nodes,install `Nodequeue` module then got `admin/structure/nodequeue`  create new nodequeue and name it as you want, then in the blow of it add nodes you want then reorder them with which sort you want.

(You can use [nodequeue API](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodequeue!nodequeue.module/function/nodequeue_load/7) to load them OR )Then in your views create  a views that want add relation to `nodequeue` the in sorting section select "queue) Nodequeue: Position (asc)". and now you have a views with node that sorted by what order you want.

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as:
>
> - A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
> - A user’s favorite music albums
> - A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
>
> Nodequeue provides a simple drag-and-drop interface to manually order any queue. Additionally, it allows nodes to be added and removed from queues without needing edit permissions to the node. Nodes can be added to queues either from a queue management tab or by links on the node teaser.